# How to make forwarding YouTube video with Python Selenium using?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I need to create a forwarding YouTube video with Python Selenium.

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys

<any_web_element>.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_RIGHT)
```

Comment: If answer helps can you close the question by accepting it :)

Answer (score 0):

To press the keys use this module and call it like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body').send_keys(Keys.SPACE)
```

try:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OIhVs0FQ8xc&list=RDOIhVs0FQ8xc&index=1'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.set_window_size(1024, 600)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
 
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body').send_keys(Keys.SPACE)
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body').send_keys(Keys.RIGHT)


soup=bs(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
res=soup.find_all('ytd-playlist-panel-video-renderer')
print(res)
```

Comment: Thanks Pygirl, code is running successfully.